# How to setup Concurrency Thread Group

Tags: concurrency, jmeter, performance-testing

I have following test plan to test concurrent user load test of a website -

[image]

Configuration set as -

```
Target Concurrency = 10
Ramp up Time = 1 
Ramp up step count = 1
Hold Target rate time = 6
```

So it's creating confusion, what I am expecting that it will send only 10 requests at a time in 1 second but the result is it sends first 10 request at a time in 1 second and continue sending requests till 60 seconds.

Why it is so?

Comment: try by keeping Hold Target Rate Time to 1 sec or/and mention Thread Iterations Limit to 1

Answer (score 0):

Keep `Hold Target Rate Time to 1 sec` to match your expectations.

The graph should reflect the settings you made.

Note: In the graph you shared, it is clearly visible that you kept `Hold Target Rate Time to 60 sec` (reflected in the graph also) which resulted in 60 seconds execution after ramp-up time.

Reference:

[Refer Concurrency ThreadGroup section in the link](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-4-stepping-thread-group-and-concurrency-thread)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I am getting your point. but my concern is about hold load for 60 sec of 10 concurrent users. If I make it 1 sec then my script will execute all threat at a time and after getting all responses , it get stops. So do i need to go with this way to test 10 concurrent user for 60 sec or any other thing i need to do ?

Comment: I didn't get your point. Do you want to run 10 threads for 60 seconds but should only send single request by each thread? please clarify your requirement

Comment: Hi. i know that is a very old post but this is what i am trying to do also. Run 10 threats for 60 seconds by only sending one request. So lets suppose i send a get request and hold all the 10 threats alive for 60 secs, Is there a way to do that or i am too confused?

Answer (score 0):

as per requirements for simulating 10 requests at a time in 1 second

```
Target Concurrency = 10
Ramp up Time = 1
Ramp up step count = 1
Hold Target rate time = 1

Keep Hold Target rate time till you want to run to test.
e.g 1 sec for running test plan for 1 sec, 1 min to run test plan for 1 min.
```